# Using Excel, or R, to figure out at what time point my data doubled

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I am very new to `R` and am trying to answer a "simple" question. I have a DataFrame of isolates and their optical densities (OD) over time.  I am looking for the point that the OD's double from the start point.

Simplified Data Frame

```
Time (mins)   R8-5081   R8-5088 R8-5095
0              0.766    0.895   0.623
15             0.531    0.593   0.436
30             0.531    0.581   0.408
45             0.522    0.593   0.407
60             0.52     0.6     0.409
75             0.527    0.612   0.416
90             0.527    0.616   0.416
```

I want the time at which the OD for R8-5081 becomes 1.06 (the first row where time = 0 is usually not the true value).

It is possible to do it in Excel, what would be the `R` style of approach?

Answer (score 0):

You should be including reproducible code with your question so we can test on your data. That said, I think this should work.

```
min(which(df$`R8-5081` >= 2 * df$`R8-5081`[2]))
```

Comment: I have no idea how to include "reproducible" code, honestly.  As I said, I'm too new to coding in general to know what to do.  That's why I'm looking here to see what I should be doing or where to go ):

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

This link is great for describing it. Basically you write some short code so we can copy/paste into R, hit run, and work with your sample data.

Comment: Do either of the answers provided give you what you need? If so, could you mark one of them as correct?

Comment: Neither did, actually. I was able to find out what to do in Excel with use of the code `=CELL("row",INDEX(Sheet1!C4:C98,MATCH(TRUE,Sheet1!C4:C98>(Sheet1!C4*2),0)))`

The R code would provide 0's reported back or no way to tell what occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will extract all row(s) where data point doubles:

```
od[which(od$R8.5081 == 2*od$R8.5081[2]), ]
od[which(od$R8.5088 == 2*od$R8.5088[2]), ]
od[which(od$R8.5095 == 2*od$R8.5095[2]), ]
```

Here, 'od' is data frame that contains the data points. (your excel/csv that can be read and stored in this variable)

If desired output is only first row where OD doubles, then;

```
od[min(which(od$R8.5081 == (2 * od$R8.5081[2]))),]
od[min(which(od$R8.5088 == (2 * od$R8.5088[2]))),]
od[min(which(od$R8.5095 == (2 * od$R8.5095[2]))),]
```

Comment: you should edit this to extract only the first observation where this occurs

Comment: Would this be applicable to all columns though?  Something that can make that data frame and make it into a vector?

Comment: You can run the command for each column as shown above, and obtain expected result.